# How to vectorize a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, matrix, vectorization

I need to vectorize this code I am using to analyse large amounts of audio data. To normalize the data I used a for loop, but would like to vectorize it to help with performance.

```
for i in range(len(state)):

    if state[i] == 0:
        savedAudio[i] = 0
    else:
        savedAudio[i] = savedAudio[i] / env[i]
```

State, savedAudio and env are just large single dimension arrays filled with readings from a sound board. I am new to the concept of vectorizing and currently do not really understand it.

Comment: You might want to try [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `numpy` module you can do something like this

```
import numpy as np

# sample inputs
state = [0,1,1]
savedAudio = [3,3,3]
env = [1,2,4]

# convert your lists to numpy arrays
savedAudio = np.array(savedAudio, dtype = 'float64')
state = np.array(state)
env = np.array(env)

# vectorized replacement
savedAudio[state != 0] = savedAudio[state != 0] / env[state != 0]
savedAudio[state == 0] = 0

print(savedAudio)
>>> [0.   1.5  0.75]
```